# How to cancel save action in Dynamics 365 CRM (UCI) with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to cancel onSave event via JavaScript depending on the result of a WebApi request to CRM. I have my function setup as an Event Handler on the main form "On Save" event type (passing in the execution context). My JS function is just an empty method like one below.

```html
checkForDuplicate = function (executionContext) {

}
```

When I press save on unmodified recod I get an error like this (in the DevTools):

```
Uncaught (in promise) - "UciError: Cannot save due to no dirty changes."
```

This error shows even if the "Enabled" checkbox is unchecked on the "Configure Event" popup screen.

Now about the canceling the save action. I have placed a call to [preventDefault (Client API reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/save-event-arguments/preventdefault) like this:

```html
checkForDuplicate = function (executionContext) {
  executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
}
```

But then I got another error in the DevTools:

```
UciError: Cannot save due to PreventDefault encountered.
```

This code [CRM 365 - Blocking the "onSave" operation when validations require FetchXMLQueries be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64420560/crm-365-blocking-the-onsave-operation-when-validations-require-fetchxmlqueri) also throws UciError: Cannot save due to PreventDefault encountered.

The entity in question is "territory".